# How to create Windows shortcut for chrome-devtools link?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Instead of copying and pasting the link for the chrome-devtools inspector (for use with node.js) each time, is it possible to create a shortcut link to access it?

I've tried the normal way to create a shortcut and if I start the url with http://devtools/..., it opens that URL, however when the "http://devtools" is changed to "chrome-devtools://devtools" (which is required for inspector to work), the chrome shortcut just opens up the default page as if it doesn't see this url.

So using this in the target for the shortcut:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome-devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@521e5b7e2b7cd66e4006a8a56cb9c4e5534a5ef/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=localhost:9229/node
```

results in the url being ignored, but changing the:

```
"chrome-devtools://"
```

to

```
"http://"
```

causes the url to be used although it isn't valid since it has to begin with "chrome-devtools://".

So it looks like shortcuts only use site addresses that are not prefixed with "chrome-devtools://".  I've tried putting quotes around the url, but that doesn't solve it.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

I'm switching from using node-inspector for debugging to google-chrome-devtools since node-inspector no longer works with the latest version of node.js and support seems to be dropping in favor of the new --inspect option on node.js.

Environment is Windows 10, node.js v6.3.1, Chrome version 53.0.2785.116 m

Comment: Chrome ignores chrome:// urls in command line for sickoority reasons. I'm not sure there's a workaround. Needs an investigation. Maybe ChromeDriver script can help. Or something like AutoHotkey automation as a last resort.